# Hive with Ruby(ROR) Integration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hive, rbhive

I have installed Hive, Hadoop
Added gem in Gemfile,

```
gem "rbhive"
```

started hive using,

```
hive -service hwi
```

But it throws exception, whenever i am executing it,

```
RBHive.tcli_connect("localhost", 9998, {:hive_version => :cdh5, :transport => :sasl, :sasl_params => {} }) do |connection|
 connection.fetch('SHOW TABLES')
end
```

Error,

```
Initializing transport sasl
Connecting to HiveServer2 localhost on port 9998
Thrift::TransportException: Broken pipe
    from /home/dheena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thrift-0.9.3.0/lib/thrift/transport/socket.rb:90:in `rescue in write'
```